# How to skip over a blank cell instead of printing a blank line in Excel subroutine?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am writing a subroutine in Excel and need to be able to skip over a cell and not print blank lines if statement is false.

The following is from a cell on my spreadsheet

```
=IF(B13="Yes",
    " We will show you how to make an Accountant's copy of your Quick Books. You will then upload the file to your secure portal on our web page every quarter, Anyone on your team can walk you through thes process.",
    IF(B16="Yes",
       "On a  quarterly basis we will review your QuickBooks On Line file, download the data to our program. We will also make all journal entries that are required",
       IF(B12="Yes",
          "We will have your vendors start mailing their invoices for you to our office. Checks will be prepared for your approval, signing and mailing. Any payments that can be made online will be done that way with your permission."
       )
    )
)
```

If the answers are No I want to skip to the next cell and not print blank lines when I do a print out. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you mean you're writing a VBA subroutine? If so please add [tag:vba] to your question

Comment: I was hoping to keep it simple and not get into VBA subroutines.